# Create 3 separate images with hover overlay with links in them

Tags: css, image, hover, overlay

Im trying to have 3 separate image links with hover image overlay however I can't seem to achieve this. Each "imgBox" needs a different name as images will be different however when I use "imgBox2" or "imgBox3" and appropriately change the class name in css, it doesn't work. Also, I entered link within the div and also does not work. Can someone show me the correct code for both of these.

page link: http://oasissoho.com/newsite/

```
<div width="100%">
<div class="imgBox" style="float:left"></div>
<div class="imgBox" style="float:left"></div>
<div class="imgBox" style="float:left"></div>
<div style="width: 226px; float:left; margin:10px 0 10px 0" >
<a   href="book-tour/"><img src="http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/book_tour.png" ></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.imgBox { width: 226px; 
 height: 226px; 
 margin:10px 18px 10px 0; 
 background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-  content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_white.png) no-repeat; } 

.imgBox:hover { 
width: 226px; 
height: 226px; 
margin:10px 18px 10px 0; 
background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp- content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_black.png) no-repeat; } 

</style>
```

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: Use classes for stuff that is the same across all elements. If you need to have some different styles and some that are the same, either use 2 classes `<div class="imgBox imgBox1">` or classes and ids `<div class="imgBox" id="img1">`

I'm not sure how the code you described doesn't work, what you included works but is obviously not what you want. Based on your description, I made the following

```css
.imgBox {
  float: left;
  width: 226px;
  height: 226px;
  margin: 10px 18px 10px 0;
}
.imgBox > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#img1 {
  background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_white.png) no-repeat;
}
#img1:hover {
  background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_black.png) no-repeat;
}
#img2 {
  background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_white.png) no-repeat;
}
#img2:hover {
  background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_black.png) no-repeat;
}
#img3 {
  background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_white.png) no-repeat;
}
#img3:hover {
  background: url(http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/consulting_box3_226_black.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div width="100%">
  <div class="imgBox" id="img1">
    <a href="/"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox" id="img2">
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox" id="img3">
    <a href="wikipedia.org"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please keep in mind, that leaving the `a` tag empty and making it a block element might actually be a bad idea. If you're using html5, you can however put the `<a>` around your `<div>` instead of vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot mmgross, it worked. However, it did create an issue, when you hover, the image becomes smaller. I don't see what's causing it.

Comment: You need to learn to organize your style definitions: You have at least 3 style-tags (I stopped counting after I found what I was looking for) and a style sheet. In your style sheet, you have a conflicting definition for `.imgBox` and `.imgBox:hover` where you set the width and height to 191px. You really should tidy up and throw stuff like that out.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually placed the css code directly into the page as it was not working when I had it in css sheet. I forgot to delete old css code from stylesheet. I added height and width to the hover like this and it worked to fix the size issue:                                                                 #img1:hover {
  background: url(wp-content/uploads/2015/03/learn1_overlay1.png) no-repeat;
width: 226px;
height: 226px;
}